# ORA-01722: invalid number on select query

Tags: oracle

```
select id + ' - ' + name from user_table order by id
```

it result an error when I tried to display it on a asp dropdown list

```
[OleDbException (0x80040e07): ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-01722: invalid number]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1692049
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForMultpleResults(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +253
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +208
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +278
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +264
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the concatenation operator is `||`, not `+`.

Try

```
select id || ' - ' || name from user_table order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are using **+** operator for concatenating values, instead use pipe operator.

```
select id ||' - '||name from user_table order by id
```